# How to visualize the basis in the unit cell of crystals?

Tags: software-recommendations, crystallography, visualization-software

Usually, the unit-cell of a crystal is made up of lattice points and basis, but all the crystallography software like VESTA doesn't show the `basis`, is there any software that could show the basis?

Comment: I think that if you obtain the primitive cell, and then remove the periodicity (converting your system into molecular), you will have your basis.

Comment: Could I remove periodicity in VESTA?

Comment: Jack, it's possible that @Camps didn't see your reply, because you didn't ping him. If Camps doesn't know whether or not periodicity can be removed in VESTA, I suggest asking that as a separate question.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out?